# If button is not pressed submit button will not be able to be pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello so I'm trying to build a question where people just have to click button but how do I stop the person from clicking next if they hadn't clicked any button yet. Please keep

Comment: If you post the code you have already written you can get a more specific answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Use some javascript to disable the button until one of the options is selected ...

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
```

from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp)

Comment: How would I put it to disabled on default

Comment: Wonderful, yes you can set it by default in the HTML. If this worked for you, please mark this as the correct answer.